# Ruby: If column exists use it, if not add to other column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-4, jsonb, smartercsv

I'm parsing a CSV and trying to distinguish between columns in `Model` and "virtual" columns that'll be added to a JSONB `:data` column. So far I've got this:

```
rows = SmarterCSV.process(csv.path)
rows.each do |row|
  row.select! { |x| Model.attribute_method?(x) } # this ignores non-matches
  Model.create(row)
end
```

That *removes* columns from the CSV row that don't match up with `Model`. Instead, I want to add the data from all those into a column in `Model` called `:data`. How can I do that?

**Edit**

Something like this before the `select!` maybe?

```
row[:data] = row.select { |x| !Model.attribute_method?(x) }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could do this. One particularly straightforward way is with [`Hash#slice!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice-21) from Rails' ActiveSupport extensions, which works like `Array#slice!` and returns a Hash with those keys that weren't given in its arguments, while preserving the keys that were given:

```
rows = SmarterCSV.process(csv.path)
attrs = Model.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym)

rows.each do |row|
  row[:data] = row.slice!(*attrs)
  Model.create(row)
end
```

P.S. This could probably be filed under "Stupid Ruby Tricks," but if you're using Ruby 2.0+ you can take advantage of the double-splat (`**`) for this compact construction:

```
rows.each do |row|
  Model.create(data: row.slice!(*attrs), **row)
end
```

P.P.S. If your CSVs are big and you find yourself having performance concerns (calling `create` a few thousand times—and the subsequent database `INSERT`s—ain't cheap), I recommend checking out the [activerecord-import gem](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import). It's designed for exactly this sort of thing. With it you'd do something like this:

```
rows = SmarterCSV.process(csv.path)
attrs = Model.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym)

models = rows.map do |row|
  row[:data] = row.slice!(*attrs)
  Model.new(row)
end

Model.import(models)
```

There are other, faster options as well in the activerecord-import docs.

Comment: That is a _dope_ one liner! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! I added a note about a gem you might find useful; take a look.

Comment: Not your first rodeo, eh? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
row[:data] = row.delete_if {|k,v| !Model.attribute_method?(k) }
Model.create(row)
```

This will remove the elements from the row hash and add the key-value pairs back to the row under a `:data` key.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `has_attribute?`

```
row[:data] = row.keep_if { |x| !Model.has_attribute?(x) }
```

Comment: I like `keep_if` but `has_attribute?` doesn't work for me.

Comment: rails 3.2+ it will work http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/has_attribute%3F  or http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-has_attribute-3F